# Configure vlan on Netgear switch via SNMP

Tags: switch, vlan, snmp, netgear

I am trying to configure vlans on a netgear GS752TSX from the Linux command line with netsnmp. I have created vlan 99 on the web interface now want to control the pvid settings, egress and tagging. I have identified these as the MIBs I need to change:

```
dot1qPvid.<port>
dot1qVlanStaticEgressPorts.99
dot1qVlanStaticUntaggedPorts.99
```

Pvid works as I expect:

```
$ snmpset -r 1 -t 20 -v 2c -c private <switch> dot1qPvid.17 u 99
Q-BRIDGE-MIB::dot1qPvid.17 = Gauge32: 99
$ snmpget -r 1 -t 20 -v 2c -c private <switch> dot1qPvid.17
Q-BRIDGE-MIB::dot1qPvid.17 = Gauge32: 99
```

and so do the egress ports:

```
$ snmpset -r 1 -t 20 -v 2c -c private <switch> dot1qVlanStaticEgressPorts.99 x 'ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00'
Q-BRIDGE-MIB::dot1qVlanStaticEgressPorts.99 = Hex-STRING: FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
$ snmpget -r 1 -t 20 -v 2c -c private <switch> dot1qVlanStaticEgressPorts.99
Q-BRIDGE-MIB::dot1qVlanStaticEgressPorts.99 = Hex-STRING: FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

But untagging the ports doesn't seem to remember my setting:

```
$ snmpset -r 1 -t 20 -v 2c -c private <switch> dot1qVlanStaticUntaggedPorts.99 x 'ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00'
Q-BRIDGE-MIB::dot1qVlanStaticUntaggedPorts.99 = Hex-STRING: FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
$ snmpget -r 1 -t 20 -v 2c -c private <switch> dot1qVlanStaticUntaggedPorts.99
Q-BRIDGE-MIB::dot1qVlanStaticUntaggedPorts.99 = Hex-STRING: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I have tried netsnmp 5.4.1 and 5.7.2.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't be surprised if Netgear's SNMP set doesn't work right. Upgrade the firmware if you can and check the latest docs. If it's still the same, I'd contact Netgear. You might have found a bug.

Comment: I've found that write operations of Q-BRIDGE-MIB on various devices to be very unreliable. Sometimes you have to do the operations in a certain order, for example. Sometimes you have to set egress and untagged in the same SNMP set command. Experiment with various methods!

Comment: Reported it to Netgear and it was a bug, which they've now resolved. @Andrew thanks, that might be useful to know in the future.